# Knockout-jqAutoComplete displays the ID value instead of the name during editing

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm using Knockout 2.2.1, JQuery 1.9.1, and Ryan Niemeyer's Knockout-jqAutoComplete 0.4.3.

The application allows the user to add a contact to a list of contacts. The contact information comes from a list of possible contacts.

We are using a span to display the names of contacts that exist in the database and data model on page load. When the user clicks the name, they have the opportunity to edit or delete the contact. We hide the span and show an input field in its place. This field is the AutoComplete field and it should show the Name of the contact.

The user can also click a button to add a new contact, which adds a new row with an input field which also uses AutoComplete.

Information edited or added by the user is persisted when a save button is clicked.

**The Problem**

When the user enters editing mode, the input displays the ID instead of the name.

Here's [an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXEZT.png) of the data displayed on page load, and here's [what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUJ4k.png) when you switch to editing mode. In the second picture, we'd like for it to display "Doe, John" instead of the primary key from the database.

Using an older version of Knockout-jqAutoComplete, this was not an issue. (We updated to the current version because there were other problems.) I can't find a version number on it, but it was used by including a Razor partial, "_jqueryAutoCompleteBinding.cshtml". The binding for this old version was:

```
//Deprecated, no longer in use.
<input data-bind="jqAuto: { autoFocus: false }, jqAutoSource: optionsProfessionalsAuto, jqAutoQuery: getProfessionals, jqAutoValue: ProfessionalId, jqAutoSourceLabel: 'displayName', jqAutoSourceInputValue: 'Name', jqAutoSourceValue: 'Id'" class="edit-data Name"  />
```

The binding we're now using is:

```
<input data-bind="jqAuto: { source: getProfessionals, value: ProfessionalId, valueProp: 'ProfessionalId', labelProp: 'Name', inputProp: 'Name', options: { autoFocus: false } }"class="edit-data Name" />
```

And here is the relevant portion of the AppViewModel:

```
 function AppViewModel() {
    //{...}

    self.addProfessionalContact = function () {
        var skip = this.ProfessionalContacts().length * 14 - 1; // rows * columns - 1
        this.ProfessionalContacts.push({
            Name: ko.observable(''),
            Specialty: ko.observable(''),
            City: ko.observable(''),
            State: ko.observable(''),
            ProfessionalId: ko.observable(),
            optionsProfessionalsAuto: ko.observableArray() //deprecated?
        });
        WireUpEditGridEvents();
        SetDisabled();
        RegisterDatePicker();
        WireUpPostAddEvents(skip, 'professionalContacts');
        $("#professionalContacts tr").last().find(".display-data").hide();

    //{...}
    }
```

(Edit 1) 
Here is GetProfessionals, as requested:

```
function getProfessionals(searchTerm, sourceArray) {
try {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET"
        , contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        , url: '@Url.Action(MVC.Professional.ActionNames.GetProfessionals, MVC.Professional.Name)?searchTerm=' + searchTerm
            , dataType: "json"
            , success: function (data) {
                var result = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    var specialty = data[i].Specialty ? data[i].Specialty + " - " : "";
                    result.push({ Name: data[i].Name + " (" + specialty + data[i].City + ", " + data[i].State + ")", ProfessionalId: data[i].ProfessionalId });
                }

                sourceArray(result);
            }
            }
        )
        .fail(function () { $.unblockUI(); $.growlUI('Error', 'Failed to get professionals. Unknown error.'); });
} catch (e) {
    $.unblockUI();
    throw e;
}
```

(Edit 2)

I think I do need some further clarification.

The getProfessionals function returns a list of type ProfessionalContactEditViewModel. This class contains several properties:

```
public class ProfessionalContactEditViewModel
{
    public int? ClientContactId { get; set; }
    public int ProfessionalId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Specialty { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Fax { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }

    public bool Send { get; set; }
    public bool ReferredBy { get; set; }

    public bool Delete { get; set; }

    //Added based on RPNiemeyer's response
    //public NameIdViewModel ProfessionalNameId
    //{
    //    get
    //   {
    //        return new NameIdViewModel()
    //        {
    //            Name = this.Name,
    //            Id = this.ProfessionalId,
    //        };
    //    }
    //    set
    //    {
    //        this.Name = value.Name;
    //        this.ProfessionalId = value.Id ?? default(int);
    //    }
    //}
}
```

Based upon RP's answer, I added a NameIdViewModel obj. which returns the Name and ProfessionalId. This, however, is not turned into an observable as a nested object, so we're now passing the entire ProfessionalContactViewModel from getProfessionals:

```
result.push(ko.toJSON(data));
```

I have removed valueProp from the input binding; it otherwise reads the same as before, but I'm still seeing a number when I edit a contact.

The browser tab also freezes for a few seconds when searching for a contact by name, and displays a completely blank list. The former of these two new issues may be due to the larger amount of data.

Comment: Can you show me what `getProfessionals` looks like? I think the issue is that your source data is a remote query and there is no context to find the `Name` of the current value, as it is just an id (`ProfessionalId`).  You could take off the `valueProp` option and then it will store/expect an object as the value like `{ Name: 'ryan', ProfessionalId: 1122 }`.  You would just need to make sure that anywhere that uses the selected value, first picks out the ProfessionalId.

Comment: @RPNiemeyer, I edited the post. Is that what you expected?

Comment: Yes! Does what I suggested make sense?  Is it possible for you to deal with the object rather than just the ProfessionalId?

Comment: @RPNiemeyer, Please see my second edit.